# Rotate an object on drag with SnapSVG

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm using SnapSVG to try and rotate an object around it's axis when it's dragged.

Using the `.drag()` method, I call this function:

```
var rotate = function(dx,dy) {
    angle = Math.atan((dx-100)/(dy-100)) * 180/Math.PI;
    this.attr({
        transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "R" : "r") + angle
    });
}
```

This calculates the angle using Pythagoras and then applies the rotation. 
The shape does rotate, but not cleanly - it jumps around and flicks over on its axis.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/apythoncoder/pen/pKVpGP) with an example

What do I need to do to get it rotating smoothly?

Comment: I feel like you probably want to store the angle each time. As you are dragging with a dx/dy, you need to know how much you have dragged by, and then add that to the angle already rotated. Plus, you need to account for the atan swapping immediately from plus to minus (if you see in the logs).

Answer (score 0):

I found the `Snap.angle()` function, which took a lot of the maths out the problem. This is how I managed to get it working smoothly:

```
var start_angle = 0;
var angle = 0;

var rotate = function(dx,dy, x, y) {
    theta = Snap.angle(350, 350, x, y)
    angle = (start_angle - theta) * -1

    this.attr({
        transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "R" : "r") + angle
    });
}

var start = function(x, y) {
    start_angle = Snap.angle(350, 350, x, y) 
    this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}
var stop = function(x, y) {
    current_angle = Snap.angle(350, 350, x, y) 

}

element.drag(rotate, start, stop);
```